# Use custom viewgroup to control click event flows

Tags: android, viewgroup

I have a custom `ViewGroup` which can scale on double tap. I want to make sure that the children of this ViewGroup receive their click events only after I make sure that touch was intended to be a single tap & not the first tap of a double tap gesture, via my `GestureListener`'s `onSingleTapConfirmed` method.

I could find a lot of tutorials to control touch event propagation & intercepting them. I am not clear as to how dispatching click events work

Any pointers?

**EDIT 1**

*Simplified Custom ViewGroup*

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    private final GestureDetector mGestureDetector;    
    private boolean mGestured = false;

    public ViewGroup(Context context) {
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }


    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        mGestured = true;
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }


    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (!mGestured) {
            mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
            mGestured = false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    private static class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }


        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            // I want to dispatch the onClick event to my children 
            // (if the event is within their bounds) here
            Log.i("custom view group", "on single tap confirmed");
            return true;
        }


        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            // Code for double tap zoom
            Log.i("custom view group", "on double tap event");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In my activity I add some children to my custom view

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("textView", "i got clicked: " + v.toString());
            }
        });

        CustomViewGroup customViewGroup = new CustomViewGroup(this);
        customViewGroup.addView(textView);

        setCustomView(customViewGroup);
    }
}
```

Whenever I double tap on top of the child text view, I see both these log statements

```
02-27 15:12:24.343  23837-23909/com.asdf.qw I/textView﹕ i got clicked
02-27 15:12:24.343  23837-23909/com.asdf.qw I/custom view group﹕ on double tap event
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it can work that way. I understand that the events are sent to the child button before you will know if the double click has occurred, by which time it is too late to tell the child not to handle the click.